# How to connect to Couchbase server 4.0(Beta) N1QL in windows?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have just installed Couchbase Server 4.0(beta) and try to run N1QL Query, but could not connect it.
When I try to run `cbq-engine.exe -couchbase http://localhost:8091/` The command prompt closed automatically. When try to use `cb.exe -engine=http://localhost:8091/`  It also does not work. Is it bug?
How to connect it?
(I am running cbq.exe from bin directory of installation)

Answer (score 1):

As documented in the [Running your first N1QL query](http://docs.couchbase.com/4.0/n1ql/getting-started.html) section of the Couchbase Server manual the port the `cbq` needs to connect to is 8093

```
cbq.exe -engine=http://localhost:8093
```

Comment: There is error message:  **ConnectEx tcp: no connection could be made because because the target machine actively refuse it. **

Answer (score 1):

There may be something you missed during installation (it happened to me more than once, and this has been signaled to the team): did you check the "Index" and "Query" checkbox, they are unselected by default, and without it N1QL doesn't run...

See the checkboxes under "Start a new Cluster" in the screenshot below:

[image: couchbase 4 installation screen]

Comment: if that's the problem, you will have to uninstall/reinstall couchbase server 4.0 I think. This has also been mentioned as a potential improvement (being able to do that without reinstalling).