# How can I check if Couchbase 4.0 server was set up with "Index" and "Query" activated (allowing for N1QL)

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Related to [this 3-year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925652/how-to-connect-to-couchbase-server-4-0beta-n1ql-in-windows).

Is a way to see if the "Index" and "Query" boxes where checked when a Couchbase server was configured?
[image: Screenshot from question referenced above, showing where the Index and Query feautures are configured.]
I am dealing with a Couchbase 4.0 server that someone else configured, and I'm having problems running N1QL-queries, frequently returning "Requested resource not found.".

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the UI, you can click on "Server Nodes". Each node in the cluster will have the services listed:

[image]

You could also use the [REST API](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/4.0/rest-api/rest-index-service.html) to find this information. For instance, if you use the /pools/nodes endpoint, you'll get a list of nodes which contains a property "services", that will list the available services. Here's a snippet of a typical response:

```
// . . . snip . . .

    "nodes": [{
        "services": ["index", "kv", "n1ql"],

// . . . snip . . .
```